# android - trying to create listview

Tags: android-activity

i'm trying to write data from sqlite to a listview. the compiler doesn't show error, but when I run the app on my phone, it crashes. please help me

```
        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("Select * from weight_listview ORDER BY `id` DESC",null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();


    String[] list = new String[] {};
    String[] weighttolist={};
    String[] datetolist={};
    ArrayList<String> List=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> List2=new ArrayList<String>();
    resultSet.moveToFirst();

    int x = 0;
    while(resultSet.moveToNext()){
        String data = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("weight"));
        String data2 = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("date"));
        String id = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        List.add(data + " " + data2);
        x++;
     }
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    if(List != null){
       weighttolist=(String[])List.toArray(new String[0]);


       String[] from = { "weight", "date" };
       int[] to = { R.id.weight, R.id.date };
       SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row, resultSet, from, to);
       listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

      // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      //         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, weighttolist);
      // ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

edit:

I successed to fix the problem but now I have another problem. I want that the listview will show 2 columns , not only 1 . I created fill row.xml , as you can see in the first code.

```
        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("Select * from weight_listview ORDER BY `id` DESC",null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();

    String[] list = new String[] {};
    String[] weighttolist={};
    String[] datetolist={};
    ArrayList<String> List=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> List2=new ArrayList<String>();
    resultSet.moveToFirst();

    int x = 0;
    while(resultSet.moveToNext()){
        String data = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("weight"));
        String data2 = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("date"));
        List.add(data + " " + data2);
        x++;
     }

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    if(List != null){
       weighttolist=(String[])List.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, weighttolist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


   }
```

Comment: First of all, it is better to use db api rather than raw query. A for your question, there must be an error in logcat when the app crashes. Try to find it. Maybe the cursor you are getting is null and then everything called on a null cursor makes the app crash.

Answer (score 0):

Well without the exact error it is hard to see what is going wrong. Here is my guess you are using a SimpleAdapter who's constructor looks like this

```
SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
```

For your second parameter you are using a Cursor not a list, your from variable are keys so you need to use a hash map I believe

Comment out your code and try this

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

int x = 0;
while(resultSet.moveToNext()){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String weight = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("weight"));
    String date = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("date"));
    String id = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    map.put("weight", weight);
    map.put("date", date);
    List.add(map);
    x++;
 }
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
if(List != null){
   weighttolist=(String[])List.toArray(new String[0]);


   String[] from = { "weight", "date" };
   int[] to = { R.id.weight, R.id.date };
   SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row, List, from, to);
   listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Comment: Alright the compiler should tell you what line it crash on if it doesn't then set a breakpoint and go though the code and see what line it crashes on

Comment: please take a look : I edited my main message , I solved half of the problem. the app runs and doesn't crash but i still have some problem. thanks for your help !!